# Destroying Friendship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently having issues with destroying a friendship in ruby on rails. The friendships are being created normally (I tested this using rails console), but deleting the friendship is not working.

Below is my controller code:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @current_friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => @current_friend.id)
    @friendship_2 = @current_friend.friendships.build(:friend_id => current_user.id)
    if @friendship.save && @friendship_2.save
       flash[:notice] = "Friend added"
       redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Can not add friend"
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id: params[:id]).first
    if @friendship.exists? 
      @friendship.destroy
    end
    @friendship_2 = Friendship.where(user_id: params[:id], friend_id: current_user.id).first
    if @friendship_2.exists?
      @friendship_2.destroy
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Friendship destroyed"
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

Below is my form for deleting the friendship:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id: @user.id),
         html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfriend", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that I added the check for the friendship existing since I just kept getting an error stating that the friendship was nil, which is my current problem.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'is not working'?  Are there any errors being reported, or does it simply not remove the records?

Comment: @BenY the records aren't removed. I added the if statements (e.g. if @friendship.exists?) because i was getting the error: 

undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line #40):     

39  def destroy
40   @friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id: 41 params[:id]).first
41
42     @friendship.destroy

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1sakExihzSkzP6wrrwmTp+Ww5+GQciGnBLzdG/ALzUfVnYtBidJa6EG5mDc7AcDChJlIxMN3hcY14K+0rGv/aQ==",
 "commit"=>"Unfriend",
 "id"=>"1"}

Comment: It looks to me like you are sending a user id when you are submitting the form, but you are using that user_id to look up a Friendship

Comment: @laertiades I am kind of confused by why that is bad? I am assuming I don't understand your statement.

Comment: I think that we need to see the controller action where @user is set.

Comment: That's part of the user's controller where I have  

 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

The add friend/delete friend choice shows up on the show user page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you're looking up the friendship with the `friend_id` (which you're supplying `@user.id` to), and that **`Friendship`** is what you're sending to `form_for`, so your form will have the `:id` of the **`Friendship`**.

But then in your `destroy` action you use `params[:id]` (the friendship id) in your query as the **friend_id** (which you've previously demonstrated should be a `User` id not a `Friendship` id.

Your code should actually be:

```
@friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

(and you shouldn't be calling `.first` on that at all because `find_by` already returns a single record)

Comment: Thanks smathy, but I'd only be able to delete one of the two sets of the friendship with that definition right?

Comment: I figured out how to delete the other friend! Before deleting the first friendship, I found the other friendship by pulling friend_id from the first friendship, then I deleted both. Thanks!